# getenv($PATH) is blank for a fork process

Tags: c, fork

So I am forking my program and I execve the same program again.

This program parses the $PATH env var at start via getenv("PATH"); but for some reason the env $PATH is empty for the child process.

```
char *path = getenv("PATH");
if(fork() == 0)
{
    execve(path, argv, NULL); 
}
else //parent
{
    wait(0);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  That use of `execve()` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you use `execve()`.  The first argument is the path to **the executable file**, not the PATH environment variable.  The third argument is where you specify the environment for the child process, and as you are passing NULL there, the child will inherit no environment variables (including PATH).

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I should have made it clear that is not the path env but the path to the file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The "reason" would be that you are passing a NULL for the last parameter of `execve`, which should be a NULL-terminated array of name=value strings, representing the environment of the new process; passing NULL means the child gets an empty environment.

You're also trying to execute the expanded PATH variable, which makes little sense to begin with.